# How to implement avatar movements in A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, macos-ventura

How can I insert movements of an avatar in react with a-frame project?.

*//

create animationMixerRef using useRef()
using playAnimation() and pauseAnimation() to start and pause the navigation respectively using start() y pause() from the object.

Within the  component, buttons have also been added to control the playback of the animation. Clicking the buttons will call the corresponding functions and manipulate the animation via the animationMixerRef reference.